# Identifying closed form of two-parameter sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, integers

I've come across a two-parameter sequence $a_{nk}$ with $n=1,2,\ldots$ and $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, and I would like to identify a closed expression for it. So far I have the elements

$a_{1k}=\{1\}\\ a_{2k}=\{1,3\}\\ a_{3k}=\{1,8,12\}\\ a_{4k}=\{1,15,60,60\}\\ a_{5k}=\{1,24,180,480,360\}\\ a_{6k}=\{1,35,420,2100,4200,2520\}\\ a_{7k}=\{1,48,840,6720,25200,40320,20160\}\ ,$

with $k$ increasing to the right.

There seems to be a lot of order in the elements, and I think there's probably a not too complicated expression for it - but I haven't been able to find one, despite trying [the integer sequence encyclopedia](https://oeis.org/) on various subsets and other ways to look for a system.

So far I've identified the following:

Looking at the second $k$ for each $n>1$ they can be described with a simple formula giving $\{3,8,15,24,35,48\}=\{1\times3,2\times4,3\times5,4\times6,5\times7,6\times8\}$.

Also each row $n$ is divisible by $n-1$ except for $n=1$ and $k=1$. Performing this division gives (neglecting all $a_{nk}$ for $k=1$)

$a_{2k}=\{3\}\\ a_{3k}=\{4,6\}\\ a_{4k}=\{5,20,20\}\\ a_{5k}=\{6,45,120,90\}\\ a_{6k}=\{7,84,420,840,504\}\\ a_{7k}=\{8,140,1120,4200,6720,3360\}\ .$

Now the previously mentioned order in $k=2$ is obvious.

But there I'm stuck. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I've realised the elements have a factor ${n+1 \choose k-1}$. Dividing out this factor leaves the elements

1

1 1

1 2 2

1 3 6 6

1 4 12 24 24

1 5 20 60 120 120

1 6 30 120 360 720 720 ,

which in itself looks pretty binomial-ish..

Comment: The last element in row $n$ is $(n+1)!/2$.

Comment: @jorgen: are you interested in criptography?

Comment: Not as such, do you see a hidden message in my sequence? :)

Comment: Cryptographic codes are built without private messages.

Comment: Sorry, no offense meant.

Comment: The same I say. My question was just by curiosity. Regards, (I am working in your question now although perhaps not find anything)

Comment: @jorgen: My English is weak so if I have misunderstood excuse me, please. It looks like you've got a two-parameter sequence but it is "complicated" so you want a closed expression for it. Can you give us that parameterization that you have?

Comment: By the two parameters I just meant $n$ and $k$, maybe parameter is not the right word?

Comment: But you must have some rule which determines the sucessive terms to calculate.

Comment: Yes, sorry, they arise as coefficients in a Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation of a function basis. I think it will be easier to find the orthogonal basis by example first and then prove it's the right one. I thought this info would just add confusion, maybe that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* You can find the numbers in your updated section as *[A008279](https://oeis.org/A008279)* in OEIS.

Comment: @jorgen: ... and your assumption, they look pretty binomial-ish was pretty good! :-)